# NumberFormatter::formatCurrency() output on different platforms

Tags: php, icu

Take the following code:

```php
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $formatter->formatCurrency('-1.23', 'EUR');
```

On Fedora 25, the output is `-1,23 €`, which is the output I'd expect.

On CentOS 7 however, the output is `(1,23 €)`; not quite explicit for a French audience.

**Where do these differences come from?** I suspect they come from the `libicu` version installed on the system, but I need confirmation about this. Also I'm not sure whether PHP uses the ICU version installed on the system, or a version that's bundled at compile time.

CentOS 7 has `libicu-50.1.2-15`, and Fedora 25 has `libicu-57.1-4`, but PHP versions are the same on both systems, and all packages come from the same repository ([remi](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/Config-en)), so if ICU was bundled with PHP, I would expect their versions to be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP in "remi" repository (and AFAIK all 3rd party repositories) uses system libicu, as there is no bundled libicu in PHP.

(the only exception in packages in remi repository for EL-6 which use libicu 50, backported from EL-7 instead of default 4.2)

Comment: Thanks Remi, I didn't expect to get an answer from you in person :) This clarifies what libicu version PHP uses. Do you think my issue is definitely related to the libicu version then?

Comment: Yes, very probably

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to update `libicu` to verify this, but I'm struggling to find an updated `libicu` package compatible with CentOS 7. In case you're interested, I've [asked this question on unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342918/30018).

Comment: Updating won't help, as you will also have to rebuild PHP to use this version.

Comment: Damn it. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll just assume this is an ICU version issue then, and accept your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround, setting output pattern:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$p = $formatter->getPattern(); // "#,##0.00 ¤;(#,##0.00 ¤)"
$p = explode(";", $p, 2);
$formatter->setPattern($p[0]); // "#,##0.00 ¤"
echo $formatter->formatCurrency('-1.23', 'EUR');
```

Tested on Fedora 25 (icu 58) and RHEL-7 (icu 50):

From [ICU Documentation - Decimal Format - Detailed description](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#details)

> If there is no explicit negative subpattern, the negative subpattern
>   is the localized minus sign prefixed to the positive subpattern.

Comment: Thanks, this would work, but my app uses several currencies / locales, and I don't want to have to maintain a list of formatters. I'll be better off switching to Fedora, which seems quite OK for server use these days.

Comment: This code is quite generic, it just drop the second optional pattern for negative values.

Comment: Interesting. That could work, provided that other locales don't *expect* the parentheses for negative numbers! I'll keep this code in mind, it can definitely be useful.

Comment: Interstingly enough, according to [this related question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/1869/47159), it looks like the use of parentheses has more to do with who you're targeting: accountants would usually expect parentheses, while the general public would expect a leading minus sign. This seems to have little to do with the locale in use. They seem to have changed the default behaviour in a recent ICU version, anyway!