# Number Format Currency giving Currency Accounting instead

Tags: php

```php
    $price = new Money(-100, new Currency('BRL'));
    $currencies = new ISOCurrencies();
    $numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    $moneyFormatter = new IntlMoneyFormatter($numberFormatter, $currencies);
    echo $moneyFormatter->format($price);
```

it should give me

```
R$ -1,00
```

But it is returning

```
(R$1,00)
```

Like if I was using  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_ACCOUNTING instead of NumberFormatter::CURRENCY

This behavior only occurs when Im running on Centos. Using macOS it works correctly.

Im using MoneyPHP to format but under the hood it uses NumberFormatter PHP Class.
https://www.moneyphp.org/en/stable/features/formatting.html

What can be wrong?

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue for CentOS, unfortunately. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42062181

Comment: The Money and ISOCurrencies classes are not part of the PHP standard. If you use a framework please name it. Your code cannot be reproduced this way.

Comment: @jspit im using MoneyPHP but under the hood it uses NumberFormatter https://www.moneyphp.org/en/stable/features/formatting.html

Comment: @DashRantic Thanks. The workaround using the Pattern worked for now.